# Mongoose Transactions - MongoError: Commited to Aborted

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with my Mongo database.

I am using Mongoose Transactions to save multiple documents to my database and they are all saved in the end and the transaction is commited, but I still get a MongoError and my app crashes:

> `MongoError: Attempted illegal state transition from [TRANSACTION_COMMITTED] to [TRANSACTION_ABORTED]`

Answer (score 31):

For me the problem was that I was not waiting for transaction commit. So I change this:

```
session.commitTransaction(); 
session.endSession();
```

Into:

```
await session.commitTransaction(); 
session.endSession();
```

Comment: `await abortTransaction()` for me